# Revmob and Chartboost appear too late (lag?)

Tags: charts, popup, revmob

I am making an iPhone/iPad application and I have the following problem: I want to pop up a revmob or a chartboost ad on my game over screen, which has a restart button. The ads do pop up, but by the time they appear, the player may press restart and go into gameplay again. And the ads end up on the gameplay screen (which I dont want) instead of ending up on the game over screen. Is there any way I can make sure that both chartboost and revmob ads pop up immediately after I make a call to their respective ad display functions?

Answer (score 3):

For Chartboost, I recommend you use the cacheInterstitial method before you call showInterstitial. By caching an ad, you are essentially taking an ad from the server and loading it temporarily onto the users device. After you have cached the ad, wait about 10 seconds or so and then call showInterstitial. This will speed up the process of showing ads.

You can also utilize the delegate method shouldDisplayInterstitial. You can set it to NO if it is not an appropriate time to show an ad. Take a look at the following links for help

http://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios
https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples

Also, email support@chartboost.com if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

With RevMob you can't do a preload of the popup, but you can do it with fullscreen, which also monetizes much better!

You can create and load the fullscreen in one place and retain it in a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) RevMobFullscreen *ad;

self.ad = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
self.ad.delegate = self;
[self.ad loadAd];
```

And then show it at the gameover screen:

```
[self.ad showAd];
```

They have an API documentation [site](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/index.html).